# How can I change the default font used in ALL plots and legends in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, stylesheet, fonts

Forgive me, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this no matter how much I research.  I really want to change the default font for all graphics, such as ArrayPlot, ContourPlot, DiscretePlot3D, etc. as well as the fonts used in any legends / axes / labels / (everything) to Times New Roman (I'm in Mathematica 10 so everything is sans serif by default).  I know that I can set all of these manually usually by using something like `Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]`, but it's killing me to do this for every single graph.  I've tried to use stylesheets to do this but I cannot figure out how to get them working.  I'm sorry that this is so basic, but if you could just provide a simple, step-by-step solution to achieve this, I would be eternally grateful.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16):

You can control the fonts that are used through a stylesheet. First, note the style definition used by the [`DefaultBaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultBaseStyle) [`GraphicsBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsBox) option:

```
Options[GraphicsBox, DefaultBaseStyle]
```

> {DefaultBaseStyle -> "Graphics"}

This means that the following options are used unless overridden:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics"}]
```

> {CellMargins -> {{4, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}, 
>    CellGroupingRules -> "GraphicsGrouping", StripStyleOnPaste -> False, 
>    PageBreakWithin -> False, GeneratedCell -> True, CellAutoOverwrite -> True, 
>    ShowCellLabel -> False, DefaultFormatType -> DefaultOutputFormatType, 
>    ContextMenu -> {MenuItem["Cu&t Graphics Selection", "Cut"], 
>      MenuItem["&Copy Graphics Selection", "Copy"], 
>      MenuItem["&Paste into Graphic", FrontEnd`Paste[After]], Delimiter, 
>      MenuItem["&Drawing Tools", 
>       FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`NotebookOpen[
>          FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["DrawingTools.nb", 
>           "PrivatePathsSystemResources"]]}]], 
>      MenuItem["&Get Coordinates", 
>       FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetCoordinates"]]], Delimiter, 
>      MenuItem["G&roup", "Group"], MenuItem["&Ungroup", "Ungroup"], Delimiter, 
>      MenuItem["Move to &Front", "MoveToFront"], 
>      MenuItem["Move to &Back", "MoveToBack"], 
>      MenuItem["Move For&ward", "MoveForward"], 
>      MenuItem["Move Bac&kward", "MoveBackward"]}, 
>    "AutoStyleOptionsHighlightMisspelledWords" -> False, 
>    LanguageCategory -> "NaturalLanguage", FormatType -> StandardForm, 
>    ShowStringCharacters -> False, NumberMarks -> False, 
>    CounterIncrements -> "Graphics", 
>    ImageMargins -> {{43, Inherited}, {Inherited, 0}}, Arrowheads -> 0.04, 
>    Dashing -> None, CapForm -> "Square", JoinForm -> {"Miter", 3.25}, 
>    LineColor -> GrayLevel[0], LineOpacity -> 1, EdgeColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    EdgeOpacity -> 1, EdgeThickness -> Medium, EdgeDashing -> None, 
>    EdgeCapForm -> "Square", EdgeJoinForm -> {"Miter", 3.25}, 
>    FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    FrontFaceOpacity -> 1, BackFaceOpacity -> 1, GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    PointSize -> Absolute[3], Thickness -> Medium, Opacity -> 1, 
>    DrawEdges -> False, StyleMenuListing -> None, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
>    FontSize -> 10, FontWeight -> "Plain", FontColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
>    FontOpacity -> 1}

In particular note the option value for the font family:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics", FontFamily}]
```

> "Arial"

So, to have Mathematica use the font "Times New Roman" you can just change the stylesheet. For instance:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Graphics"], FontFamily->"Times New Roman"]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

Let's see this in action:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotLabel->"FooBar"]
```

[image]

There may be other [`GraphicsBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsBox) options that may need adjusting, e.g., [`DefaultLabelStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultLabelStyle), which can be handled in the same way.

**Addendum**

A comment requested support for PDF export as well. PDF export uses the "Printout" style environment, so one needs to add:

```
Cell[StyleData["Graphics", "Printout"], FontFamily->"Times New Roman"]
```

to the style sheet as well. Another, perhaps better possibility, is to use All. So, the following should work:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Graphics", All], FontFamily->"Times New Roman"]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Yes, I think the hidden point of all similar questions is 'how can I know which options/styles to adjust?'. "Graphics" is one of them, then Label/Axes-style options come in play, not to mention TraditionalForm etc.

Comment: One can see richness of the setup by trying to set size and color aswell: `Cell[StyleData["Graphics"], FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
 FontSize -> 28, FontColor -> Black]` and use this to compare: `{Style["FooBar", "Graphics"],
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, Pi}
   , AxesLabel -> {"FooBar", "FooBar"}
   , PlotLegends -> "Expressions", ImageSize -> 400
   , PlotLabel -> "FooBar"] // Labeled[#, "FooBar"] &}`

Comment: It seems that when I `Export` a figure like this to PDF, the new font style is not preserved. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: I mean, I know that if I save the graphics using the context menu (right click -> Save Graphics As...) then the font will be preserved, but that method has other issues, such as imprecise output and lack of automatibility.  I very much prefer to use `Export`.

Comment: @Szabolcs PDF export uses the "Printout" environment, so you need to also specify `Cell[StyleData["Graphics", "Printout"],FontFamily->"Times New Roman"]`. I will add this to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and did not give you a proper minimal example. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/58XgVADU In fact, I already set the printing style environment to `"Working"`, for reasons unrelated to fonts (I just want to prevent [downscaling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6093559/695132) for `Legended` figures).  It seems that the font style isn't followed if I export something that isn't represented as a `GraphicsBox` (but contains `GraphicsBox`es within). The typical case is a `Legended` figure where the legend isn't contained within the plot frame (the default case).

Comment: @Szabolcs I've reported the issue to the pdf export development team. Are you interested in workarounds? I have two. One involves modifying an internal function, and the other involves going through a slightly more elaborate approach when exporting to pdf (basically, handcrafting a Notebook object instead of relying on Export to do so).

Comment: Thank you for reporting it. Yes, I am interested in the workarounds. I had to use this today. Would you like me to ask a new question specifically about this problem?

Comment: There's no rush.  Enjoy your Thanksgiving weekend! :-)  [The question can wait.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160580/12)

Comment: This no longer works in 12.1.0. Are you aware of a workaround?

Comment: @Szabolcs it works for me with the given example in `12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)`

Comment: @CATrevillian It works for you for PDF export? Please check the SetOptions code under Addendum. I was testing it on macOS.

Comment: The description I have in the bounty was not clear enough. What I am looking for is a simple method to change the default font for all graphics, with a single setting for the entire session, in such a way that it applies to exported PDFs. The method you show in the addendum works for 12.0.0 and earlier, but not for 12.1.0.

Comment: any ideas for newer versions of Mathematica? None of these `SetOptions` tricks change anything.

Comment: @CarlWoll Is there a way to do this globally? I tried your code above and found it only works on the current notebook.

Answer (score 6):

Try to see if this works for you. (add all the type of plots in the command below you want to set)

```
SetOptions[{Plot,ListPlot,ArrayPlot,ContourPlot,DiscretePlot3D},
    BaseStyle->{14,Directive[FontFamily->"Times New Roman"]}];
```

For `BarLegend`, it does not use `BaseStyle` so add this

```
SetOptions[{BarLegend},LabelStyle->{14,Directive[FontFamily->"Times New Roman"]}];
```

And now do

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,-1,1},PlotLabel->"This is my plot", 
      AxesLabel->{"this is X","this is Y"}]
```

etc...

It will have the font family and size indicated in the `SetOptions` command for all plots.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is close, but it doesn't appear to change the text that appears in certain types of plot legends, such as "BarLegend."  How would I account for that as well?

Comment: @JohnTravolski I have not tried it with `BarLegend`. This might be affected by the options of the plot used with the legened. It might have different baseStyle. It looks like BarLeged uses `LabelStyle` to set the font which does not have a `BaseStyle` option.

Comment: In newer versions of Mathematica (I'm on 13.0, Mac) the `BaseStyle` option doesn't seem to affect anything. Supplying the directive to the plot function directly works though. Any ideas?