# Change the default font in all plots and legends, even when exporting to PDF

Tags: graphics, export, notebooks, stylesheet, pdf-format

This is a followup to:

- [How can I change the default font used in ALL plots and legends in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160504/12)

[Carl Woll gave a great answer there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160506/12): change the `"Graphics"` style of the current notebook's stylesheet.  This is simple to do and indeed affects the style in all `GraphicsBox`es.

Unfortunately, the style change does not stick when we export a legended figure to PDF.

**Question:** How can we work around this problem and preserve the new style even when exporting to PDF?

---

**Demonstration:**

We set the `"Graphics"` style for all style environments:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Graphics", All], FontFamily -> "Times"]
    },
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
 ]
```

Additionally, we change the printing style environment to `"Working"`. Otherwise `Export` would use the `"Printout"` environment for labelled plots, which would [downscale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6093559/695132) everything.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

Let's try exporting these two plots:

```
plot1 = DensityPlot[x, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> "Plot 1"]
plot2 = DensityPlot[x, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> "Plot 2", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Both use the Times font when displayed in the notebook, but `plot2` will revert to the default font when exported to PDF:

[image]

[image]

---

*Note:* To be more precise, the problem appears when we export something that is not represented as a `GraphicsBox`. This is the case with `Legended` expressions when the legend is placed outside of the plot frame. `Row[{plot1}]` also doesn't export correctly.

Comment: Strongly related: [Default styles for Exporting to PDF, EPS and SVG](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139948/280). My answer to the question explains the logic behind the solution by Carl Woll and also provides an alternative method (but Carl's approach is better).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've reported this issue to the import/export team. One possible workaround is to use export on a notebook object representation of the graphics object. For example:

```
pdfExport[file_, expr_] := Module[{nb},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        nb = CreateDocument[expr, Visible->False, Options[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions]],
        Export[file, nb],
        NotebookClose[nb]
    ]
]
```

Your examples:

```
pdfExport["plot1.pdf", plot1];
pdfExport["plot2.pdf", plot2];
pdfExport["rowplot.pdf", Row[{plot1}]];
```

look correct to me. Another workaround is to modify an internal symbol, I can provide this if the above approach proves unsuitable.

*(Internal symbol redefinition)*

For completeness, here is the workaround where I modify an internal symbol:

```
DownValues[System`ConvertersDump`createVectorExportPacketExpr] = ReplaceAll[
    DownValues[System`ConvertersDump`createVectorExportPacketExpr],
    Notebook[a__] :> Notebook[a, Options[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions]]
];
```

It is also possible to modify the first DownValue of `` System`ConvertersDump`createVectorExportPacketExpr ``, but I think this version is better.

Comment: Actually, this seems to export at A4 size. I would be very much interested in a solution which allows me to export to specific sizes.  For example, the following sets the graphics box size to be 8 cm wide, while allowing the legend to take up as much space as necessary. It also sets the tickmark font size to 8pt.  `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 8*72/2.54, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 8]]`  I would like to preserve these measurements while exporting to PDF. The page size should match the content, and not be A4 size.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: if I set the printing style environment to Working, then Export already does that.  The comment should have been: how to produce the same PDF page size as Export while still fixing the issue asked about in the main question?

Comment: Hi Carl, do you have any tips on how to preserve the page size while still fixing the issue in the above question?  Perhaps you have a patch for the built-ins (I think you mentioned something like that, but I'm not sure)?

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm not sure what goes wrong with the page size. If you want to try modifying an internal function, you can do: `DownValues[System`ConvertersDump`createVectorExportPacketExpr] = 
 DownValues[
   System`ConvertersDump`createVectorExportPacketExpr] /. {Graphics, 
    a__} -> {Legended, Graphics, a}`. Then, just use `Export` as usual, not `pdfExport`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry about the messed up ticks. I provided a better workaround in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work well.

Comment: Same comment as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160504/how-can-i-change-the-default-font-used-in-all-plots-and-legends-in-mathematica#comment561816_160506). I am wondering if you have a workaround for Mathematica 12.1.