# SciDraw - Cannot reproduce first plot on the tutorial - No Latex-type fonts appearing

Tags: plotting, graphics

I managed to download and install SciDraw, following the instruction in the User's Guide and Reference Manual. I am using Mathematica 11.2.

I have tried to reproduce the plots created in Section A3.1.2

```
(*first plot*)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, ImageSize -> 72*{2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1];
(*second plot*)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
FrameStyle -> Larger, ImageSize -> 72*{2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1];
(*show*)
GraphicsGrid[{{%%, %}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> 0]
```

and I do get a very similar result to what shown on the tutorial, the only (yet crucial) difference being the fonts used on the axis. I would like to get the Latex-looking fonts presented on the SciDRaw tutorial, but I do not, I get the default fonts

[image]

As forewarned in the "Known issues with latest Mathematica releases" section on the SciDraw'S web page https://scidraw.nd.edu/, I get the error message SetDelayed::write: "Tag BoundingRegion in BoundingRegion[...] is Protected.". This should only affect the ability to use the BoundingRegion function, if I understood correctly.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: The code you show has nothing to do with SciDraw, it only uses built-in functions. Up to Mathematica 9.0, the default font was a serif one (like Times), but since 10.0, the default is a sans-serif (like Helvetica). You can of course change the font of labels and other elements with optons like LabelStyle, FrameStyle, etc.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160504/12 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160580/12

Comment: @Szabolcs, I see thanks a lot. Actually, maybe I could take advantage of your presence, and ask something else, yet related. I would like to try MaTeX but on your page you mention GhostScript is needed. But on https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/ I find only versiob for Mac OS, is it still needed for Windows? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Smerdjakov For Windows, you should install MikTeX (LaTeX distribution that also contains GhostScript).

Comment: Thanks to all, I will try immediately.

Comment: @Smerdjakov Yes, Ghostscript is needed on all platforms. There's a link in the MaTeX description: http://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html Last time I tried, the Ghostscript included with MiKTeX was not usable. I recommend using the official Ghostscript.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks for pointing this out, I was actually quite struggling. Now, it is working. Thanks all