# Is the option 'WindowTitle' working in 12.1 for Windows?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

It is not possible to change to option `FullFileName` at `WindowTitle` in the window of Global Preferences (version 12.1 in Windows 10).

Does anybody else has this problem?

Comment: It works for me on Mac.  What steps are you using and what's the result?

Comment: @BrettChampion Does not work for me on macOS, M12.1.0, but at the moment I am unable to make a clean start and I have maybe 10 notebooks open, some saved and some Untitled. Steps: Option Inspector, set Global Preferences, search for Window Title. Observe that the default setting is Automatic. Change it to FullFileName using the drop down. It simply does not change. It still shows Automatic.

Comment: A number of the options in Notebook Options > Window Properties are not allowed to be set at the Global scope.  WindowTitle is one of them...  I don't recall the exact motivation off of the top of my head.

Comment: @ihojnicki So this is normal, and it was the same in 12.0 and before? Just to confirm.

Comment: @ihojnicki Are you aware of any solutions to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160504/12)? Carl Woll's method no longer works in 12.1, which turns out to be a big practical problem for those of us who have long and complicated notebooks that produce publication figures.

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes.  I think that list was updated again v12.0.   And as for your other question, I think I would need a better description of what "doesn't work".  At first glance it mostly definitely uses Comic Sans if I spec that for the Graphics style in the  private stylesheet.

Comment: @ihojnicki Please check Redmine #843. I'm clarifying the description there now.