# Applying Style to Around objects

Tags: output-formatting, style, around

How do I apply `Style` to `Around` objects? Are there any workarounds, resource functions or custom solutions available? Thanks for your help.

[image]

Code:

```
Style[Around[10, 1]
 , 20, Red
 ]
Style[
 Around[10, {1, 0.5}]
 , 20, Red
 ]
```

---

**EDIT**

I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Around"}]
```

> {Selectable -> False, ShowStringCharacters -> False,
> TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{#1,
> StyleBox["[PlusMinus]", "AroundSmall"],
> StyleBox[#2, "AroundTiny"]}] &),   TemplateBoxOptionsTooltip -> None}

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "AroundAsym"}]
```

> {Selectable -> False, ShowStringCharacters -> False,
> TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction -> (SubsuperscriptBox[#1,
> StyleBox[RowBox[{"-", #2}], "AroundSmall"],
> StyleBox[RowBox[{"+", #3}], "AroundSmall"]] &),   TemplateBoxOptionsTooltip -> None}

---

**EDIT II** Adding a toy example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
t = Transpose@{Range[10, 20], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 11]};
data = Around @@@ t;
ListLinePlot[Callout[#, Style[#, Blue]] & /@ data, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Red]]
```

[image]

With a `Gray` color (instead of `Blue`) it is still usable.

Comment: Do you have any experience setting up a custom stylesheet?  It might be needed to control the various styling elements in an Around object

Comment: No I don't. I was hoping to glean some info from FullForm, but didn't make much progresss or I would have written a custom function.

Comment: what do you get from `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Around"}]` and from `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "AroundAsym"}]`?

Comment: @kglr I have updated the post.

Comment: thank you Syed.

Comment: do you want to use the same font size for all elements  (`x`, `y`, `z`, `+`, and `-`) in  `Around[x, {y,z}]` ?

Comment: I guess it should still look and feel like an Around object with `Uncertainty` displayed with slightly smaller fontsize than the `Value`. What would WRI choose to do if they wanted to incorporate this functionality at a later date?

Comment: @Syed - the functionality exists right now. The style definitions for `Around` objects are stored at the stylesheet level, and to change them you need to modify them there. You can either create your own custom stylesheet, or modify it on a per-notebook method by adapting the code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160506/9490).

Comment: @Syed something like that? `Style[Around[10, {Style[1, Red], Style[0.5, Green]}], 20, Red]`? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @bmf Interesting!! Compare the output of the regular: `Around[10, {1, 0.5}]
+Around[10, 0.2]` with `Around[10, {Style[1, Red]
   , Style[0.5, Green]}] +
 Around[10, Style[0.2, Blue]]` as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg5Lk.png). Can certainly write this as an answer although there is more going on there as we can see.

Comment: @Syed I saw that kglr and JasonB got engaged in the comments. I think that the best thing to do is to give them some time and see if they can come up with a more complete and satisfactory answer. I will get back to this post to check once I am done from the office :)

Comment: @bmf - I was just trying to point OP in the right direction :-)

Comment: @JasonB. thanks for letting me know. I thought that there was a way to manipulate the $\pm$ elements as well :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be an oversight that an explicit font color is specified in the style sheet. For example:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "AroundTiny"}]
```

> {FontSize :> 0.8 Inherited, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.4]}

So, one possibility is to create your own versions of "AroundTiny" and "AroundSmall":

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[], 
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["Around"], TemplateBoxOptions->
            {
            DisplayFunction->(RowBox[{#1, StyleBox["\[PlusMinus]", "MyAroundSmall"], StyleBox[#2,"MyAroundTiny"]}]&)
            }
        ],
        Cell[StyleData["MyAroundTiny"], FontSize :> 0.8` Inherited, FontOpacity -> 0.6`],
        Cell[StyleData["MyAroundSmall"], FontSize :> 0.9` Inherited, FontOpacity -> 0.6`]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

Then:

```
Style[Around[10, 1], Red]
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic!!!

Answer (score 10):

The following seems to work, albeit not at the level of the $\pm$ symbols.

```
Style[Around[10, {Style[1, Red], Style[0.5, Green]}], 20, Red]
```

> [image: around]

Following the logic above, one is able, of course, to manipulate the `Style` in any given expression.

Comment: I think this has utility, if one wants to see Around components getting used in a computation as I mentioned in a previous comment. With pattern matching more can be done. Since Around objects follow many syntax variations, a consolidated solution would be the ultimate goal. I can't say that I know what it would look like. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Syed totally agree with you and this is why I was hesitant to write this as a first answer. I was kind of hoping for a more complete approach by someone.